# How to mypy typehint an attrs validator attribute

Tags: python, attr, python-attrs

Given the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import attr


@attr.define(frozen=False)
class ExampleAtt:
    x: str = attr.field()

    @x.validator
    def check(self, attribute: attr.Attribute, value: str) -> None:
        expected_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        if value not in expected_values:
            raise ValueError('error')
```

I get the mypy error:

```
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Attribute"  [type-arg]
```

How can I type hint an attrs `attribute` used within a validator ? I've tried what's in the code above, as well as `attr._make.Attribute` found from `type(attribute)`.

Comment: If you aren't actually using the value of `attribute` in the function, the type probably doesn't matter; you could just use `typing.Any` or omit the type hint altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a maintainer of attrs.

I gather you're using the `--disallow-any-generics` Mypy option. A small problem here is that `attrs.Attribute` isn't really a generic class, but the Mypy attrs plugin treats it as such because it's more useful that way. I think we'll change this in the future so it's generic in attrs too.

But in the meantime, what you want to do is using a string annotation instead. Here:

```py
import attrs


@attrs.define()
class ExampleAtt:
    x: str = attrs.field()

    @x.validator
    def check(self, attribute: "attrs.Attribute[str]", value: str) -> None:
        expected_values = ["a", "b", "c"]
        if value not in expected_values:
            raise ValueError("error")
```

I've switched to the new `attrs` namespace and cleaned up the example a little. Note that the type of the `attribute` parameter, `attrs.Attribute[str]` is now generic (`Attribute[str]` vs just a bare `Attribute`), and the type annotation is in quotes (i.e. a string).

Another solution would be to use `from __future__ import annotations` but that's a bigger change, so I would use the first.

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned in the [docs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attrs.Attribute), but evident by the [code](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/f1bb113cfed830a06f1ca89e4432f2b11f020604/src/attr/__init__.pyi#L111) and `mypy`s output you provided, `attr.Attribute` inherits from `Generic` which makes it itself a generic type.

To get rid of the error, provide the the concrete type for this case (here `str`, as you want to validate attribute `x` which is of this type).